# Why does list.end() not change when new item is added?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I am working on a programm which has two lists. One of the list stores objects. The other list stores pointers to items of the list containing the objects. When a new item is added to the object list I want to get the pointer to the object. But I always get the same pointer returned.

Since my program is to big now I made a new, smaller one to show you the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class C_Test
{
    public:
        int a;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<class C_Test> Testlist;
    C_Test A;
    C_Test B;
    Testlist.push_back(A);
    C_Test * p = &*Testlist.end();
    cout << p << endl;
    Testlist.push_back(B);
    p = &*Testlist.end();
    cout << p;  
}
```

Result:

```
0x22fe20
0x22fe20
```

I would expect the programm to print out two different pointers since the end of list should have changed? Why does it give me two times the same pointer?

I really would appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: Why would you expect it to change actually?

Comment: `&*Testlist.end()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: `.end()` is not the last item nor an item at all. It's a *fake* item which goes *after* the last one. Because it's just a marker It does not exist in the list itself.

Comment: I only programmed linked lists before and I would expect that .push_back() adds a new node to the list which should have a new address? I am fairly new to C++ so I am sorry if that is a dumb question.

Comment: It is being added indeed, but `.end()` doesn't do what you think it does. If you want to see the last element you should use `--list.end()` or `list.back()`.

Comment: Also, don't use `class` with type names like in `std::list<class C_Test>` in C++. It's redundant.

Comment: @Cornstalks My compiler gives me no error massage. Would `&*(Testlist.end())` be better or is the whole idea wrong?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: Whole idea is wrong. There is nothing at `end()` that you can safely dereference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters dereferencing the iterator returned by the member function `end` has undefined behavior.

I think you mean

```
 C_Test * p = &Testlist.back();
```

Comment: With your code I unfortunately get the following error:

`[Error] cannot convert 'std::list<C_Test>::iterator* {aka std::_List_iterator<C_Test>*}' to 'C_Test*' in initialization`

Comment: @A.Pope This have nothing common with the code I showed.

Comment: @A.Pope It seems you run some different code. If so then close this question selecting the appropriate answer and ask a new question regarding to your new code.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't notice you replaced .end() with .back() as well. That is why I got an error. Thank you all very much for your help :)